# Appending mulitple objects to an object with dynamic names

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-5

I have a function that requests and receives back several configs. The individual configs for example look like this:

```
{
  "blue" : {
    ...
  }
}
```

I get each of these configs by calling another function. I then want to add the returned configs into one big object.

Here's how I get each config:

```
    var bigConfigList = {};

    foo.forEach(function(colourProvider) {
      var config = colourProvider.getConfig().config; // returns { "blue" : { ... } }
    });
```

Inside the above, I want to append `config` to `bigConfigList` so that the result is something like this:

```
bigConfigList = {
  "blue" : { ... },
  "red" : { ... },
  "green" : { ... }
}
```

Similarly to how I could do `array.push()` to get a similar result in array. But as a big object.

**1. I don't know what the name of the first key in the object will be. It could be green, red, blue etc**

**2. I need to do this in ES5**

I've tried various things like:

```
var bigConfigList = {...bigConfigList, config} // doesn't work because ES5 and also puts the config in as an object not with the first value

object.assign() // not sure why but I don't think this is appropriate

bigConfigList[config] = [config] // this is just plain wrong I know but it felt close
```

Comment: This should work `bigConfigList = {...bigConfigList, ...config}`. You have to destructure the config as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use for...in to iterate the properties of an object, and add them to `bigConfigList`:

```
var bigConfigList = {};

foo.forEach(function(colourProvider) {
  var config = colourProvider.getConfig().config;
  
  for(var c in config) {
    if(config.hasOWnProperty(c) {
      bigConfigList[c] = config[c];
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to destructure your config as well. Please refer to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const config1 = { "blue" : { b: 1 } }

const config2 = { "red" : { r: 2 } }

const config3 = { "yellow" : { y: 3 } }

let bigConfig = {};

[config1, config2, config3].forEach(config => { bigConfig = {...bigConfig, ...config} });

console.log(bigConfig)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you expecting the combined result in object. you just declar the variable as object.

```
var bigConfigList = {};

    foo.forEach(function(colourProvider) {
      var config = colourProvider.getConfig().config; // returns { "blue" : { ... } }
      bigConfigList = Object.assign(bigConfigList,config);
  });

console.log(bigConfigList); // gives the result in object;
```

or declaring the variable in array. and use the `array.push` operation

```
var bigConfigList = [];

    foo.forEach(function(colourProvider) {
      var config = colourProvider.getConfig().config; // returns { "blue" : { ... } }
      bigConfigList.push(config);
  });

console.log(bigConfigList); // gives the result in array;
```